# can there exist a partition that is $\delta(t)-$fine but the refinement of the parition isnt?

Tags: real-analysis

In other words, if $P$ and $Q$ are both tagged partitions where $P\subset Q $ can there exist a gauge $\delta(t)$ such that $P$ is $\delta(t)-$fine but $Q$ isn't?

I don't see how this is possible since by definition all partition points of $P$ are also partition points of $Q$. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Your title and question don't match. Saying that $P$ is a refinement of $Q$ means that $Q\subset P$, not $P\subset Q$.

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry I fixed the title, I meant $P\subset Q$ where $P$ is delta fine but $Q$ isn't

Comment: In that case, no, it can't exist for the reason you state.